# Get list of members by looking at the their latest status

Tags: mysql, sql, membership

I have a complicated case that I am simplifying to a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. Say we have a MySQL table containing a bunch of clubs and many students. Each student can join multiple clubs and they can also leave at any time.

For MVCE purposes, let's consider the table below:

```
/* Table: membership */
Club    Student     Date        Status
ABC     Alice       1/1/2020    Joined
ABC     Bob         1/1/2020    Joined
ABC     Charlie     1/2/2020    Joined
XYZ     Charlie     1/2/2020    Joined
ABC     Alice       1/6/2020    Left
ABC     Alice       1/12/2020   Joined
ABC     Charlie     1/12/2020   Left
XYZ     Alice       1/12/2020   Joined
```

What statement do I use to find all students in club ABC on `1/9/2020`? The answer should be `Charlie` and `Bob`. If we change the date to `1/12/2020`, the answer should be `Alice` and `Bob` since `Alice` joined and `Charlie` left that day.

Here's what I have tried which doesn't return what I want:

```
SELECT Student
FROM membership
WHERE
Club = "ABC" AND
(SELECT MAX(Date) WHERE Status="Joined" ) > (select MAX(Date) WHERE Status="Left") ;
```

Also, the above considers the current membership. How would I make it the membership at a particular date?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure that wasn't already done. This isn't an easy SQL, and being forced to try whatever in the Question isn't helpful to anyone trying to Answer it nor to anyone trying to find an Answer. I think it was better in it's first revision, as this failed attempt to create the SQL is actually just confusing. All the information needed to Answer this was there already.

Comment: @Strawberry They're asking a HOWTO Question. Providing an MCE for those was never required. See Robert Harvey's Answer to [Got review ban for reviewing as 'Looks OK' for a question which I still think is OK](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401146/got-review-ban-for-reviewing-as-looks-ok-for-a-question-which-i-still-think-is/401157#401157). Trying to force it is misguided. This isn't a debugging Question.

Comment: @Strawberry I think the issue of this post is obvious. If has examples of that they want a user/club returned if the user is a member of the club on the date that's specified in a query. So if a user has joined on the 1st, then left on the 10th, re-joined on the 21st and left on the 30th, then they're not to be returned if the query asks for members on the 15th, but is to be returned if the query asks for members on the 5th or the 25th. It's not clear what is unclear to you.

Comment: @Strawberry This is actually a very relevant case. Instead of multiple huge sparse tables, the above is a more compact data representation. For the sparse representation, each club would be a huge sparse table where rows are all possible dates and columns are all the students. So for a particular date, if a student is a member, the cell is populated as 1, otherwise 0. Precisely because membership does not change that often, this allows for the compact table above. As I am not a SQL expert, trying to find the correct statement is not trivial.

Comment: I can only refer you again to the accepted answer at the link provided in my original comment

Comment: The one about "Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?"?

Comment: I very much disagree that the link @Strawberry referred to here is relevant. They seem to just say that your post is unclear, but not saying how or what they do not understand from/about it. And the query-solution to this Question is not trivial (at least not to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can match your records of "Joined" to the corresponding "Left" or `null` if there is none, then you're pretty much done. The logic I'd apply is that records that corresponds to a "Joined" must be by the same "club" and "student". The date is a bit more tricky, since it's possible to have this scenario:

```
Club    Student     Date          Status
ABC     Alice       2020-01-01    Joined
ABC     Alice       2020-01-02    Left
ABC     Alice       2020-01-03    Joined
ABC     Alice       2020-01-04    Left
ABC     Alice       2020-01-05    Joined
```

The corresponding record can be found by the "Left" record that has a date that is greater than the "Joined", but the earliest of those.

Since the "Joined" don't always have a corresponding record, as in the scenario above where there's none for the last "Joined", I've used a self-join using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT joined.club,
       joined.student,
       joined.date AS joindate,
       left_.date  AS leavedate
  FROM Membership AS joined
  LEFT JOIN Membership AS left_ ON joined.club = left_.club         -- must match
                               AND joined.student = left_.student   -- must match
                               AND left_.Status = 'Left'            -- match to "Left"
                               -- Only the minimum date of the dates
                               -- ..greater or equal to "Joined" date
                               AND left_.date = (SELECT min(date)   
                                                   FROM Membership min
                                                  WHERE 1 = 1
                                                    AND min.club = left_.club
                                                    AND min.student = left_.student
                                                    AND min.date >= joined.date 
                                                    AND min.Status = 'Left')
 WHERE joined.Status = 'Joined'
```

Resulting in:

| club | student | joindate | leavedate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Alice | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-06 |
| ABC | Bob | 2020-01-01 | null |
| ABC | Charlie | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-12 |
| XYZ | Charlie | 2020-01-02 | null |
| ABC | Alice | 2020-01-12 | null |
| XYZ | Alice | 2020-01-12 | null |

To get memberships on a date, you just have to add:

```
  AND joined.date <= '2020-01-06'
  AND coalesce(left_.date,'9999-12-31') > '2020-01-06'
```

or

```
  AND '2020-01-12' BETWEEN joined.date
                       AND coalesce(date_add(left_.date,interval -1 day),'9999-12-31')
```

Since `BETWEEN` is inclusive, I've subtracted a day. I've used `coalesce` to ensure that when there's no corresponding "Left", the date compared is always the maximum date.

However, grouping the records with identical "club", "student", and "Joined"-date the above is equivalent to:

```
SELECT joined.club,
       joined.student,
       joined.date     AS joindate,
       min(left_.date) AS leavedate
  FROM Membership AS joined
  LEFT JOIN Membership AS left_ ON joined.club = left_.club
                               AND joined.student = left_.student
                               AND left_.status = 'Left'
                               AND left_.date >= joined.date
 WHERE joined.status = 'Joined'
 GROUP BY joined.club, joined.student, joined.date
```

Adding the date would then instead be using `HAVING` since it's on the result:

```
HAVING '2020-01-12' BETWEEN joined 
   AND coalesce(date_add(`left`,interval -1 day),'9999-12-31')
```

---

I'd advice you to use `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` instead of just of `DATE`, since you're going to get into a pickle with this scenario:

```
Club    Student     Date          Status
B52     Peter       2020-10-03    Joined
B52     Peter       2020-10-03    Left
B52     Peter       2020-10-03    Joined
```

Or

```
Club    Student     Date          Status
B52     Benny       2020-10-01    Joined
B52     Benny       2020-10-03    Left
B52     Benny       2020-10-03    Joined
```

The "Left" is greater or equal to any of the "Joined", and it will appear as if neither Peter nor Benny is a member on the 3rd and as a result also not on any later date.

You can also resolve the scenario if you include an **ID** (which I'd advice you to always do for any table!) for your table and check that a "Left" record always came in later than a "Joined" record, instead of checking that `left_.date >= joined.date`.

Making the "Left" date *strictly* greater then the "Joined" seems to fix the issue, but then no one will effectively be able to leave on the same date that they joined.

Also note that the query using `GROUP BY` will eliminate the duplicate "Joined" date for Peter.

---

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bc566c6a94cadb364029ed2c55b12093)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Student
FROM
    Membership
WHERE
    Club = "ABC" AND Date = "2020-1-12";
```

Comment: This returns empty. I am trying to get the students that are still in the club and exclude the ones that have left.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question, Ill update my answer in a few minutes